# Bypass Windows 10 UAC "This app has been blocked for your protection."

Tags: security, uac, windows-10-preview

I ran into this problem when trying to install the USB (MTP) drivers for my Samsung Galaxy S4. Windows will not run the driver installer.

[image]

It seems the reasoning is the publisher is not trusted. My account is an administrator. Running as an administrator does nothing. **Smart Screen is disabled** and User Account Control is set to never notify.

How can I bypass this and just run the installer? I don't much appreciate Microsoft telling me I absolutely am not allowed to run an executable.

This appears to be a new problem with Windows 10.

*I was able to download up-to-date drivers that are apparently properly signed, they installed without a hitch, and MTP started working. Either way, this problem is probably independent of my particular situation, and someone may want to bypass it for other reasons in the future.*

Comment: MTP is integrated with Windows. Are you sure you need these drivers?

Comment: It appears so. Plugging in the device in MTP mode bring up what Windows sees as a CD drive that contains these drivers. Regardless, I was able to download up-to-date drivers that are apparently properly signed, they installed without a hitch, and MTP started working. Either way, this problem is probably independent of my particular situation, and someone may want to bypass it for other reasons in the future.

Comment: I've ran into exactly same problem in windows 8. However, in all those cases it was broken installer. When I re-downloaded them, I could run them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I end up doing it's removing the certificate for the .exe file. That way it became a regular app and smart screen or UAC didn't blocked it.
The utility I use was http://www.fluxbytes.com/software-releases/fileunsigner-v1-0/

Comment: While I'd find a more recent (and apparently "acceptably" signed) version of the file before, I went ahead and tested this and the executable managed to run. Seems like this is a solution. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Thanks for this. This helped me with HP programs such as the Recovery Manager being blocked on Windows 10.

Comment: How to fix for an msi?

Comment: I did this, but it didn't work. I ran CMD as Admin (just to be safe) and entered `"C:\Users\[My Name]\Downloads\FileUnsigner.exe" D:\Samsung_Mobile_USB_Driver.exe` but it just came back as `0: Failed trying to unsign D:\Samsung_Mobile_USB_Driver.exe. Access to the path 'D:\Samsung_Mobile_USB_Driver.exe' is denied.`

Comment: @SarahofGaia: Did you really think that was going to work on a CDROM?

Comment: @Joshua: But it wasn't a CDROM; it was a program that showed up when I plugged in my phone to my computer via the USB drive.

Comment: Either way, the error message means either you don't have write permission to the container or somebody else has the file open already; and since number 2 really shouldn't be true; your phone must have been presenting it readonly.

Comment: That's weird. Any way to change that?

Answer (score 13):

Launching `CMD` as an administrator and running the executable corrected the untrusted publisher error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @raystafarian I disagree, he asks how can I get bypass this and run the installer.  The solution which I used to get around the exact same issue is listed in my post, launch the installer from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: @Ramhound given the time of the post from the release date the chances are that the user is running this in a non commercial environment and has access to either someone who can run an elevated command prompt or is an administrator themselves.  As for launching an application through an elevated command prompt this does and has solved the issue not just for myself but for others who have had the same issue. So to be clear as for anyone else who can't seem to understand this....open an elevated command prompt (run cmd as admin) then launch your install file from there, it bypasses this issue

Comment: @Ramhound I'm disagreeing with the fact of you saying it downs'twork when it does.  I had the exact same issue.  If I right clicked on the install file and ran as administrator then it didn't work and I faced the same issue.  Running it through the elevated command prompt instead or right clicking and going "run as administrator" produced different results and I can replicate the issue and results.  Do you want youtube video of proof before you will accept this???? have you even tried to replicate the issue the OP had and then tried my non existent workaround????

Comment: @Ramhound it is not identical to what the author tried as it was not launched through an elevated command prompt.  Having to strip the certificate from the file is something that can be avoided.  I get what you say about them doing the same thing, but in this case they clearly didn't and the fact still remains that the workaround solved the issue.  When you work in development and testing, things often don't work as expected and there are always issues with new software/releases.  Unless you tested in the same way and tried the exact workaround comments then you can't say it's wrong.

Comment: @smelllllllllll - Fine;  You are right;  I am wrong.

Comment: Despite the controversy in the comments, this worked perfectly for me. A nice, simple solution..

Comment: This works like a charm... ty alot

Answer (score -2):

I'm not completely sure. But the required steps should be like these:

Go to Action Center. In the left side, you should see an option Windows SmartScreen. That should give you an option to disable it.

Another solution is to Control Panel->User Accounts. There you should see an option Change UAC settings. Lower down that scroll bar and your problem should go away.

Comment: These are already addressed in the question. SmartScreen is disabled.